# SwiftUI: Adjust bounds of ScrollView

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, swiftui-scrollview

I am trying to scale a view horizontally using `scaleEffect` and `MagnificationGesture`.
It is almost working as I want with the exception that the `ScrollView` does not resize when its child view resizes.

Is there a fix for this? Any solution would be greatly appreciated.

To reproduce:

1. run the code below
2. scale up the image horizontally with the pinch gesture
3. notice that the `ScrollView` scrolls as if the image still has the same size.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var currentAmount: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var finalAmount: CGFloat = 1

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            Image(systemName: "star")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .scaleEffect(x: finalAmount + currentAmount, y: 1)
                .gesture(
                    MagnificationGesture()
                        .onChanged { amount in
                            self.currentAmount = amount - 1
                        }
                        .onEnded { amount in
                            self.finalAmount += self.currentAmount
                            self.currentAmount = 0
                        }
                )
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: 300)
    }
}
```

Comment: Scaling effect is only a visual effect, real frame remains the same - so if you want to change real view size then change its frame.

Comment: That’s it! Work on anything other than scale!

Answer (score 1):

This view does it.

```swift
struct HorizontalScaleView<Content: View>: View {

    @ViewBuilder var content: Content

    @State private var currentAmount: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var finalAmount: CGFloat = 1

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                content
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .scaleEffect(x: finalAmount + currentAmount, y: 1)
                    .frame(width: (finalAmount + currentAmount) * geo.size.width, height: geo.size.width)
                    .gesture(
                        MagnificationGesture()
                            .onChanged { amount in
                                self.currentAmount = amount - 1
                            }
                            .onEnded { _ in
                                if self.finalAmount + self.currentAmount >= 1 {
                                    self.finalAmount += self.currentAmount
                                } else {
                                    self.finalAmount = 1
                                }
                                self.currentAmount = 0
                            }
                    )
            }
        }
    }
}
```